# Privileged instruction in C

Tags: c, windows, parallel-processing, privileges, ports

I'm having some problems with C. I am trying to program a parallel port in Windows 7 Professional x64 in VS 2010 Ultimate.
Since I do not have a parallel port, I'm using a converter from USB->Parallel and Windows installed the drivers correctly.
I've soldered 8 LED-s on the end of the parallel connector and they are all working fine when I connect the USB into the computer.
Now, I would like to control the parallel port via my program written in C which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
/********************************************/
/*This program set the parallel port outputs*/
/********************************************/

void main (void)
{
//clrscr();            /* clear screen */
_outp(0x378,0xff); /* output the data to parallel port */
getch();              /* wait for keypress before exiting */
}
```

The program gets compiled and runs but I get an error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00f313a5 in portovi.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
```

I have read that port IO is disabled in windows NT machines and that you need a specific driver to do it. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: conio.h is a terrible, terrible way to write things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways around this. See [here](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html) for instance.

Comment: I don't know if I did everything that said. I put the inpoutx64.dll into system32/drivers folder. I should recompile the project and include the downloaded library?

Comment: Won't help.  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/2d52ceda-7c0b-4fd7-bf99-cbd12b2be898

Comment: I've came across this article in the link you gave me: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us/ it seems it's the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

Your USB->parallel converter has drivers to create a virtual parallel port.  It implements the Windows parallel port API.  It does not implement the PC/AT parallel port register-level API, and even if you were permitted to write I/O port `0x0378`, you wouldn't find anything there.  Only real PC/AT parallel ports on the system bus (ISA or PCI) use that register.

Comment: I've considered that in fact too. Could I write insted of 0x0378 to my USB hub device ID that I've connected it to?

Comment: @Juraj: No.  The USB hub is already is use by all the other USB drivers on your computer, talking directly to it would be a bad idea (and also horribly complicated).  WinUSB lets you directly communicate with certain types of USB devices, but I don't think parallel ports are among them.  Check whether your USB->parallel cable manufacturer provides a bit-banging API.  For example, http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_232R-01_Bit_Bang_Mode_Available_For_FT232R_and_Ft245R.pdf

Comment: Thank you for clearing some things out. No, the cable doesn't support it. I bought http://www.delock.com/produkte/gruppen/USB+Adapter/Delock_USB_11_parallel_adapter_61330.html . I think I should get one of those then.